# CMake variable ignored on first build (CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS)

Tags: cmake, cuda

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I am loading an environment variable as such:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} $ENV{CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -lineinfo --default-stream per-thread --disable-warnings")

message("CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS = ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")
```

However on the first build attempt after a clean (`rm -r build`) it will simply ignore the `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` variable, causing the build to fail:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-g -O3 -fmax-errors=1" ../../

make -j8
```

Console ouput:

```
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS =  -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -lineinfo --default-stream per-thread --disable-warnings
...
/home/mad/workspace/automy-system/vision/src/DeBayerFilter.cu(132): warning: integer conversion resulted in truncation
/home/mad/workspace/automy-system/vision/src/HeightMapFilter.cu(115): error: identifier "__ldg" is undefined
```

The build fails because my CUDA code requires a certain compute capability which is enabled by the `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS`.

On a second attempt and there after it works just fine.

`cmake version 3.5.1`

Comment: You may print (with `message` command) value of `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` variable after the `set` command and check whether it is correct or not. In any case, it is needed more info (more code) about your project, and more detailed description of the fail instead of "causing the build to fail".

Comment: Thanks. It seems the problem is not the loading of the env variable but rather the whole CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS is ignored on the first build attempt. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` variable, `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` variable is set at `project(CUDA)` call, when the compiler is detected. So appending to that variable should be performed **after** the `project` call:

```
project(MyProject CUDA)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} $ENV{CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -lineinfo --default-stream per-thread --disable-warnings")
```

If CUDA is detected with `find_package(CUDA)` (in old CMake versions which doesn't natively support CUDA), then appending the flags should come after `find_package(CUDA)`, which sets the `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` variable:

```
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} $ENV{CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -lineinfo --default-stream per-thread --disable-warnings")
```

---

The reason why inverse order works, but only on the non-first configuration, is that variable `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` is actually **cached**: The first `project()` call sets the variable's value and stores it into the cache. Futher `project()` calls detect that the compiler is already checked and do not re-set the variable.